# Run Ubuntu on imac with busted graphics card

Tags: system-installation, graphics, apple

I have an old imac (2012) with a busted graphics card (AMD 1GB). The computer has 16 GB of RAM and an i5 sandy bridge processor (3.1 GHZ). OSX runs without the graphics driver using onboard graphics but is extremely sluggish. If I install ubuntu, will it give me better performance using the onboard graphics?

I ask this as I believe that OSX restricts the RAM that OSX uses when its using integrated graphics. Would Ubuntu allow me to use more RAM and hence give me better performance?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can test it yourself without installing, make a bootable ubuntu usb / disk, and test using the live-boot.

Comment: True. Was wondering if anyone had some wisdom that would save me the effort.

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxgiR-5C-zQ) can help?

Comment: No wisdom will be better than trying. It will all depend on the exact state of your hardware. Note that the "effort" is *very* minimal. You don't need to install anything, simply boot off of a live USB stick. If it looks OK, then you can install.

Comment: Installed Xubuntu but the performance is horrible. It seems that Xubuntu ships with some default ATI.AMD Radeon graphics drivers. I'm pulling my hair out trying to find a way to disable this.